# Formatting regex strings causes regex pattern characters to be escaped

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to put some variables into a regex, but also maintain a regex pattern.

```
regex = 'set groups {group} routing-instances (?P<routing_instances>[\w\W]+) interface {logical_interface}'.format(
        group=group,
        logical_interface=logical_interface
    )
```

However, it escapes the escape characters:

```
ipdb> regex                                                                                                                                             
'set groups GROUP1 routing-instances (?P<routing_instances>[\\w\\W]+) interface a10.555'
```

Comment: try prefixing your string with r''

Answer (score 1):

Use raw strings:

```
regex = r'your \regex \here'
```

Also, it doesn't really matter because your string doesn't actually contain the double slashes, it's the *textual representation* that contains them.